# Optimal algorithm to find desired input to black box

Tags: python, algorithm

I have a computationally expensive black box. Given a value x, it outputs a noisy value y and the std dev of y. (yes, it's Monte Carlo). I know that y(x) is monotonic and smooth.

I want to find the input x that'll output y_target (within error) with the least amount of calls to the black box.

I use Python to call the black box and read the results from it. I've tried to hack together a recursive linear regression method, but I'm not sure what the optimum algorithm would be.

This is what that code looks like ('parameters' is the full set of parameters which the black box needs):

```
def interpolateWithBlackbox(x0, x1, target, parameters, parameterToVary, log, y0: ufloat = False, y1: ufloat = False, precision = 0.1, xmin = 0, xmax = 100) -> ufloat:
"""Should work with an arbitrary black box that will output a monotonic and smooth y(x)."""
log.write(f'Checking between {float(x0):.5} and {float(x1):0.5}\n')
if not y0:
    y0 = blackbox(x0, parameters, parameterToVary, log)
if not y1:
    y1 = blackbox(x1, parameters, parameterToVary, log)
a = (y1 - y0) / (x1 - x0) #Slope
#y0 = x0 *a + b, t = x * a + b
x = (target - y0) / a + x0
if abs(x - x0) <= precision or abs(x - x1) <= precision: #We have found the parameter we wanted.
    log.write(f'Found x = {x:0.5} for target of {target}\n')
    return x
elif x > x0 and x < x1: #We can interpolate to increase precision by going recursive.
    log.write(f'Found x = {x:0.5} for target of {target}. Increasing precision\n')
    x = x.nominal_value
    return interpolateWithBlackbox(x - precision, x + precision, target, parameters, parameterToVary, log, precision=precision)
elif (x0 == xmin and x < xmin) or (x1 == xmax and x > xmax): #No valid x value satisfies the solution.
    log.write('No valid x value satisfies the solution.\n')
    return None
else: #We have extrapolated that the position is outside the checked interval. Going recursive to change the interval...
    log.write(f'Found x = {x:0.5} for target of {target} with extrapolation. Changing interval.\n')
    x = x.nominal_value
    if x < x0: #We are below the checked interval.
        newx0 = max(xmin, x - (x0 - x))
        newx1 = x0
        return interpolateWithBlackbox(newx0, newx1, target, parameters, parameterToVary, log, y1=y0, precision=precision, xmin=xmin, xmax=xmax)
    else: #We are above the checked interval.
        newx0 = x1
        newx1 = (min(xmax, x + (x - x1)))
        return interpolateWithBlackbox(newx0, newx1, target, parameters, parameterToVary, log, y0=y1, precision=precision, xmin=xmin, xmax=xmax)
pass
```

EDIT: To answer some of the questions below:

I can control the noise level from the black box with how much computational time I give it. So given the same input, it'll return the same size std dev (with a bit of noise on that too).

The smoothness is at least C1 and I'm pretty sure C2.

I can't bound the derivatives beyond that y(x) is monotonic. I'll also know the sign of the first derivate, but that is use case dependent.

Comment: Do you know the noise distribution, or at least some kind of amplitude ? Can you tell anything quantitative about the smoothness ?

Comment: If you have a tight upper bound on the noise amplitude, a dichotomic search that stops when you fall in [Yo - N, Yo + N] will do.

Comment: Is the sd always the same when you invoke your blackbox multiple time with the same x?

Comment: You know it is smooth. But can you bound any of the derivatives?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Here would be my first approach.

You have started with a set of observations.

```
meas_x = [x1, x2, ..., xn]
meas_y = [y1, y2, ..., yn]
meas_std_y = [std_y1, std_y2, ..., std_yn]
```

You want to create a function `est_f(x)` that estimates the data points and can be used to predict where `f(x0) = y0` might be.

If `est_f` never crosses `y0` then you want to keep measuring `f` at a finer and finer grid until either you've found a place where it does, or you've convinced yourself that it doesn't.  But if `est_f` does cross `y0`, you can use some variation on binary search to figure out approximately where, then measure there.

The interesting part is how to define `est_f`.  Presumably we have a bunch of distant measurements, but also several ones close to the crossing that we want to find.  So ideally we'd like to do a least squares fit of the nearby points, and then use that least squares fit to estimate `f`.  But what does "nearby" mean?

Instead of answering that, let's do a *weighted* least squares fit, but with a weighting that prioritizes nearby points, and discounts distant ones.  However in a least squares fit, distant points have a ton of leverage, so we need to **really** discount them by a lot.  For example if we expect the error to be proportional to distance, then we expect the square error to be proportional to distance squared.  So if we divide the weight by distance squared, they will actually still have a lot of weight.  So let's divide by distance to the fourth.  And scale that by a factor that will cause the distance penalty to be bigger if you have more data.  (So if you have lots of points, you'll only really use the closest ones.)

The tricky bit is that the weighting depends on the `x` that we are estimating for.  So rather than weights being numbers, they are functions of `x`.  But otherwise this will be the standard formulas, such as can be found on slide 3 of https://ms.mcmaster.ca/canty/teaching/stat3a03/Lectures7.pdf.  And it isn't as hard as it sounds.

```
def meas_weight_funcs(meas_x, meas_std_y):
    # This does our weight estimate.

    # The purpose of these two is to say if we have lots of points, use distant points less.
    x_diff = max(meas_x) = min(meas_x)
    dist_scale = len(meas_x) / x_diff**2
    def w(i):
        x_i = meas_x[i]
        std_y_i = meas_std_y[i]
        def w_func(x):
            return 1 / (std_y_i + dist_scale * (x - x_i)**4)
        return w_func
    weight_funcs = []
    for i in range(len(meas_x)):
        weight_funcs.append(w(i))
    return weight_funcs

def values_at(funcs, x):
    # Helper function to turn an array of functions to their values at x.
    values = []
    for i in range(len(funcs)):
        values.append(funcs[i](x))
    return values

def array_plus_const(v, v_const):
    # Helper function to add a constant to every term of an array.
    return [v_i + v_const for v_i in v]

def array_product(v, w):
    # Helper function to find pairwise products of 2 arrays assumed same
    # length.
    answer = []
    for i in range(len(v)):
        answer.append(v[i] * w[i])
    return answer

def average(weights, values):
    # This calculates a weighted average.
    return sum(array_product(weights, values)) / sum(weights)

def est_f(meas_x, meas_y, meas_std_y):
    weight_funcs = meas_weight_funcs(meas_x, meas_std_y)
    def fit(x):
        weights = values_at(weight_funcs, x)
        avg_x = average(weights, meas_x)
        avg_y = average(weights, meas_y)

        # Calculate x_i - avg_x and y_i - avg_x
        adj_x = array_plus_const(meas_x, -avg_x)
        adj_y = array_plus_const(meas_y, -avg_y)

        # Factoring out w_i*(x_i - avg_x) from B1 in the slide.
        adj_weights = array_product(weights, adj_x)

        # Now the coefficients of our line.
        B1 = sum(array_product(adj_weights, adj_y)
            ) / sum(array_product(adj_weights, adj_x))
        B0 = avg_y - B1 * avg_x

        return B0 + B1 * x

    return fit


meas_x = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
meas_y = [0.5, 0.5, 3.7, 10.1, 14]
meas_std_y = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

f = est_f(meas_x, meas_y, meas_std_y)
for i in range(41):
    x = i / 10
    print(x, f(x))
```

Again, this just creates an estimate for the underlying function you are measuring.  You still need logic for the initial brute force search for a point above/below, and then logic to try to use your estimate to find the next point.  But both of those should be more straightforward than this piece.